# List comprehensions that get rid of the corresponding elements in parallel lists

Tags: python, list

I want to get rid of all of the zeros in an array and in another array, get rid of the elements corresponding to the indices of the ones that did have zeros in the first array.

I have:

```
A = [2,3,2,4,5]
P = [0.1,0.3,0.4,0.5,0]
new_P = [x for x in P if P[x]!=0]
new_A = [x for x in A if P[x]!=0]
```

What am I doing wrong? For `new_P`, for example, I get a blank array.

Comment: I'm guessing that `x` is the element, and not the index?

Comment: Think about what `x` represents in this context.

Comment: Please clarify the question. I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve

Comment: @pzp What I thought was that the expression in new_P would look through each element in P and see if the element equalled 0. Now that I know that is wrong, I still can't correct it - -I tried removing the x, for example.

Comment: So `x` is an element in `P`. Now what is `P[x]` then? What should it be?

Comment: @ChrisHalcrow I'm trying to get P to be [0.1,0.3,0.4,0.5] and A to be [2,3,2,4] (ie getting rid of the 0 in the P and the corresponding index of A).

Comment: @pzp I thought P[x] should be P? but it gives me an error

Answer (score 1):

- Your first list comprehension will not work because your iterating
  by reference, but you're trying to access an element by index. Python is going to raise an `IndexError`. Change your comparison to test with `x` instead of `P[x]`: `new_P = [x for x in P if x != 0]`.
- Your second list comprehension will not work for the exact reason the first will not work. But the same fix does not apply to your second  list comprehension. You need to use `zip` to iterate over **both** `P` and `A`, testing if the current element in P is a zero.

  ```
  >>> A = [2,3,2,4,5]
  >>> P = [0.1,0.3,0.4,0.5,0]
  >>> new_P = [el for el in P if el != 0] # testing using x not P[x]
  >>> new_P
  [0.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5]
  >>> new_A = [el[0] for el in zip(A, P) if el[1] != 0]
  >>> new_A
  [2, 3, 2, 4]
  >>>
  ```

Comment: @python_learner Sure, glad I could help :) As a side note, I suggest [learning more about list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) before using more.

Answer (score 0):

How about just zipping the lists together and processing their elements together?

```
a = [2, 3, 2, 0, 5]
p = [0.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6]

a, p = zip(*[(a, p) for a, p in zip(a, p) if p != 0])
```